# Ссылки с редиректом в sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap

Возник такой вопрос.
На сайте используется ЧПУ на всех страницах. При запросе к странице по простому url вида index.php?route=... происходит редирект на это же страницу но с ЧПУ.

Проблема в том, что при генерации sitemap уходит очень много времени и ресурсов на создание ЧПУ.

Вопрос вот в чем, если в сайтмап пихать простые ссылки (index.php?route=...), при этом при переходе будет редирект на ЧПУ, как к этому отнесутся поисковики. Стоит ли так делать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну в целом должно сработать, ничего криминального в этом нет, способ не запрещён поисковыми системами. Поисковик должен грамотно прочитать редирект и проиндексировать новую страницу.